# Difference between 'voting' and 'casting a vote'

Tags: word-usage, american-english

What's the difference between them? A man was talking to another person while the elections were being held. I overheard them. But I'm confused here. English is not my mother language and I have always heard people saying 'did you vote for someone', not did you 'cast a vote for someone '.

Comment: It seems to me that the question is a valid one. I was going to suggest that there was no difference in meaning when describing the action of an individual, but "voting" may also denote a collective activity ("Voting continued all day"), which can only clumsily be described by "the casting of votes".

Comment: Context is always important.

Comment: @Irefuteitthus One puts the object first in these cases: *“Vote casting continued all day.”* Or maybe *vote-casting* or *votecasting*.

Comment: @irefutitthus by this you mean casting of vote is used to describe the activity an individual is doing however voting is a collective activity?

Comment: @tchrist ...or vole-catching.
You're right that one could say "vote casting"; it's not a natural substitute for "voting".

Comment: @ArdisEll Both "voting" and "casting a vote" are apt expressions to describe the action of an individual. But if you wanted to describe the collective process or activity involved in democratic elections, I think you would refer to "voting", rather than "casting a vote", or even "casting votes".

Comment: Mostly the same, but "casting a vote" tends to associate more closely with the physical act and process of recording the vote, whereas "voting" tends to associate more with the conceptual act of making choices that get recorded.

Comment: Also, even with an individual, *casting a vote* refers to a single instance. You usually cast multiple votes on different races or amendments when voting.

Comment: "Casting a vote" is "voting", but "voting" is not necessary "Casting a vote"! ^^

Answer (score 1):

"Casting a vote" is now a "figure of speech" for voting.

In the old days, one would vote by filling out a paper ballet, and "casting it" into a voting receptacle.

But nowadays, votes are recorded electronically.

Comment: Voting systems continue to vary greatly, depending on country, type/official status of election, official regulations, and existence (or absence) of relevant infrastructure.

Comment: In California we still use paper ballots, so "voting" consists of "marking your ballot" (recoding your choices with regard to all offices to be filled and measures to be decided) and "casting your ballot" (feeding the completed ballot into the polling station's ballot box). Nevertheless, I agree with the main point here that "casting your vote" is now widely understood as a figurative way to say "voting."

Comment: *Votes are recorded electronically*—this is a definite Americanism. Hardly any other democracies (or pseudo-democracies) use voting machines.   And in the really old days (e.g., middle-late 19th century Canada), one announced one's vote publicly.  This made sure that the guys who bought your vote were getting their money's worth.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Brazil, Belgium, Canada, Estonia and India also use electronic voting, so *there are* democracies who adopt it. I disagree it's an Americanism. You probably meant that this doesn't apply yet to the UK and most countries in the world.

Answer (score -1):

"Voting" is a form of the simplex verb to vote. Beside the vast number of simplex verbs there is another vast number of compound verbs and still another vast number for which there is no standard name but a lot of names.

Beside the simplex verb to vote ist the verbal expression to cast one's vote meaning to put one's voting slip/ballot into the box. Actually there is no difference in meaning between to vote and to cast one's vote. The verbal expression consisting of the noun from to vote and a general verb is just a variant with another structure though.

In any language there is a great number of verbal expressions. Some examples in English:
to announce, to make an announcement,
to pay attention to someone/something,
to draw attention to something,
to bear/keep something in mind,
to have a break,
to call for a break

Just as you can fill a dictionary with compound verbs you can fill a dictionary with
verbal expressions. It is an important class of verbs as many ideas are best expressed with such verbal expressions.

Answer (score -4):

The act of voting indeed is distinguishable from the act of casting a vote.

The analogy is that I decided to paint my house.  I haven't done so yet.  The act of deciding does not realize a painted house.  The act of voting does not ensure that I will submit my ballot for counting.

Comment: I completely disagree, when I physically put a slip with a box crossed into the ballot box *I am voting*.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I agree with you. What Runty is describing is an analogy of the combination of choosing one's preferred candidate and making up one's mind to vote. "Voting" or "casting a vote" is the process of carrying out the intention. If I fill in my postal vote paperwork but don't post it or take it to a polling station I haven't voted.